# Android Check If Logged In

Tags: android, android-asynctask, return

I'm trying to make an easy method to check if a user's saved login credentials are correct... So far I have:

```
public boolean checkLogin() {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", "");
        if (userName.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i("UserName", "UserName not found.");
            return false;
        }

        String password = prefs.getString("password", "");
        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i("Password", "Password not found.");
            return false;
        }


        mCheckTask = new CheckSavedLogin(userName, password, this);
        mCheckTask.execute((Void) null);


        return mCheckTask.execute((Void) null);//make this return true/false
    }
```

and also:

```
 public class CheckSavedLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        public final String mUserName;
        public final String mPassword;
        public boolean success;
        public Context context;

        CheckSavedLogin(String userName, String password, Context context) {
            mUserName = userName;
            mPassword = password;
            this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://173.242.94.66/scripts/appLogin.php");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", mUserName));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseStr);
                success = json.getBoolean("success");

                Log.d("Response", responseStr);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return success;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
                storeLoginDetails(mUserName, mPassword);
                //RETURN TRUE HERE?
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }
```

I just can't figure out how to make this all return "true" or "false" based upon the respone

Comment: Hi! Why not you use `sessionToken` to check whether you are already logged in or not?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I will provide a callback.

```
public interface LoginHandler
{
    onLoginComplete(boolean didLogIn);
}
```

Then I would register the handler in the AsyncTask before executing.

```
asyncTask.setHandler(new MyLoginHandler());
asyncTask.execute(0);
```

and then back in the calling activity when it fires, you can retrieve the result through your handler.

```
public class MyLoginHandler implements LoginHandler
{
   public void onLoginComplete(boolean didLogIn)
   {
      //Do what you want with didLogIn
   }
}
```